# Bad level value for property and can't set level for java.util.logging.FileHandler

Tags: java, logging, properties, java.util.logging

It's a school homework: I have to build a custom logger class capable of logging from anywhere in my projects.

I cannot use anything else but **java.util.logger**.
I'm using a properties file located in a /conf folder in my project.

I get this error:

> Bad level value for property: java.util.logging.FileHandler.level
>
> Can't set level for java.util.logging.FileHandler

I think that's why my debug() method can't print "ddd" in my file and also why can't I format file with this string i set:"[%1$tc] - [%2$s] [%4$s] [%5$s] %n".

I can't get what mistake I could have made in conf file or in code: imports are correct, I have no errors/warnings on code.

I know that I should never user absolute path but I don't think this is my problem, path will be fixed after I resolve this issue.

This output of my try.log in my /test folder:

> 03-Jan-2018 14:01:03 logger.classLogger warning
>
> WARNING: attention please
>
> please 03-Jan-2018 14:01:03 logger.classLogger error
>
> SEVERE: error
>
> 03-Jan-2018 14:01:03 logger.classLogger info
>
> INFO: info

This is my .properties file:

```
.level=ALL
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append = true 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1000000 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 100 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern =  %t/Log%u%g.log
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = "[%1$tc] - [%2$s] [%4$s] [%5$s] %n"
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter =  java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

This is my class:

```
  public class classLogger {

  Logger logger;
  FileHandler fh;
  SimpleFormatter sf;

  public classLogger(String classname){

    this.logger = Logger.getLogger(classname);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

    try {
      String path = "D:\\myprojects\\logger\\conf\\logging.properties";
      FileInputStream configFile = new FileInputStream(path); 
      LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(configFile);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
    }
 
    try {
      String directory = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\E520user\\Desktop\\test"; 
      String filename = "\\try.log";
      this.fh = new FileHandler(directory+filename);
    }
    catch (IOException ex1) {
      
    }

    this.sf = new SimpleFormatter();

    //set formatter
    fh.setFormatter(sf);

    //add handler
    logger.addHandler(fh);

  }

  public void error(String msg){
    logger.severe(msg);
  }

  public void warning(String msg){
    logger.warning(msg);
  }

  public void info(String msg){
    logger.info(msg);
  }

  public void debug(String msg){
    logger.fine(msg);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    IRSLogger log = new classLogger(classLogger.class.getName());
    log.warning("attention please");
    log.error("error");
    log.debug("dddd");
    log.info("info");

  }
}
```

Comment: What is IRSLogger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried it out on my Mac, and it works fine

```
$ cat try.log 
"[Wed Jan 03 14:35:22 GMT 2018] - [classLogger warning] [WARNING] [attention please] 
""[Wed Jan 03 14:35:22 GMT 2018] - [classLogger error] [SEVERE] [error] 
""[Wed Jan 03 14:35:22 GMT 2018] - [classLogger debug] [FINE] [dddd] 
""[Wed Jan 03 14:35:22 GMT 2018] - [classLogger info] [INFO] [info]
```

I however also get this message: `Can't set level for java.util.logging.FileHandler`

can you try and remove `java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE` from your properties file?

**TIP**

You should remove the `"` form this line: `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = "[%1$tc] - [%2$s] [%4$s] [%5$s] %n"`

**EDIT: This works on my computer**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class ClassLogger {

  private Logger logger;
  private FileHandler fh;

  public ClassLogger(String classname){

    this.logger = Logger.getLogger(classname);

    try {
      String path = "/Users/myUser/Workspace/stackoverflow/test/src/main/java/logging.properties";
      FileInputStream configFile = new FileInputStream(path);
      LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(configFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
      String directory = "/Users/myUser/Workspace/stackoverflow/test/src/main/java/";
      String filename = "try.log";
      this.fh = new FileHandler(directory+filename);
    } catch (IOException ex1) {
      ex1.printStackTrace();
    }

    //add handler
    logger.addHandler(fh);
  }

  public void error(String msg) { logger.severe(msg);}
  public void warning(String msg) { logger.warning(msg); }
  public void info(String msg) { logger.info(msg); }
  public void debug(String msg) { logger.fine(msg); }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassLogger log = new ClassLogger(ClassLogger.class.getName());
    log.warning("attention please");
    log.error("error");
    log.debug("dddd");
    log.info("info");
  }
}
```

logging.properties

```
.level=ALL
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append = true
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 100
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern =  %t/Log%u%g.log
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = [%1$tc] - [%2$s] [%4$s] [%5$s] %n
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter =  java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

It outputs in `try.log`

```
[Wed Jan 03 15:27:55 GMT 2018] - [ClassLogger warning] [WARNING] [attention please] 
[Wed Jan 03 15:27:55 GMT 2018] - [ClassLogger error] [SEVERE] [error] 
[Wed Jan 03 15:27:55 GMT 2018] - [ClassLogger debug] [FINE] [dddd] 
[Wed Jan 03 15:27:55 GMT 2018] - [ClassLogger info] [INFO] [info]
```

Comment: That was a previous name, haven't noticed... 
But it still doesn't work, same error if I run with classLogger

Comment: I am thinking it does not find the properties file.
Can you add `ex.printStackTrace();` in both your catch blocks? You might be getting a FileNotFoundException there

Comment: Added and run again, same problem. I'm pretty sure that properties file can be found, because otherwise error wouldn't be "bad value for property" maybe I should write something else and not just FINE? 
Other try catch is surrounding a file creation, and try.log file it's always created (I check last time it's modified everytime I run my project)

Comment: There is no exception in your console when you run ? 
What if you set a bogus path for the properties file? Is it the same behaviour?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\myproject\conf\ggg.properties if I set a wrong path

Comment: I removed " from the format line and restarted my IDE, now I can't run project because it can't find an older class I was using "IRSFormatter", I will check this out, maybe it's a problem with IDE

Comment: can you try and remove `java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE` from your properties file?

Comment: I removed the old class from project, now I can compile and run again, also removed that line and it doesn't work at all, same error

Comment: For reference, I added my working code to my answer.

Comment: One more thing, seems stupid but make sure there is no space at the end of your lines in the properties file. `java.util.logging.FileHandler.append = true` works, `java.util.logging.FileHandler.append = true ` doesn't. I'me pretty sure this is the issue actually :) because `FINE` exists but not `FINE `

Comment: I removed all spaces, tried and failed. So I copied your code (except for paths) and your .properties file. 
I saw that you haven't got SimpleFormatter, so i tried to delete it from my previous code. Nothing. Seems like I can't make it work

Comment: I removed the SimpleFormatter as you specify it in the properties file. Do you still get the `Can't set level for java.util.logging.FileHandler` error even without the space at the end of the line? copy/pasting might have put a space. Please make sure again that there is no space or invisible character at the end of the lines

Comment: OK. I restarted my PC, now I run it almost correctly i can use debug() method and write in append but can't use my format. I'll figure this out, thank you so much for your patience. Appreciated so much :)